# Why does QGraphicsView::update( const QRegion& ) cause the whole widget to be updated?

Tags: c++, qt, qregion

I have a large, complicated graphics view that takes a lot of processing to draw, and so I only want to redraw part of it (an OpenGL video display) each frame, leaving the rest (various child widgets etc) unchanged.

However, when I call update() with a QRegion, the paintEvent's region is the full size of the widget, so the whole screen gets redrawn every time. There doesn't appear to be any call to update() with no parameters (at least, not my version thereof)

What might be causing the paint event to have the full screen in it?

```
void GLGraphicsView::updateVideoRegion(const QRegion & r)
{
    //this function called from outside...
    LOG4CXX_DEBUG(_logger, "updateVideoRegion " << r.boundingRect().x() << " " << r.boundingRect().y() << " " << r.boundingRect().width() << " " << r.boundingRect().height());
    update(r);  
}

void GLGraphicsView::update()
{
    LOG4CXX_DEBUG(_logger, "update(all)");
    QGraphicsView::update();
}

void GLGraphicsView::update(const QRegion& region)
{
    LOG4CXX_DEBUG(_logger, "update(region) " << region.boundingRect().x() << " " << region.boundingRect().y() << " " << region.boundingRect().width() << " " << region.boundingRect().height());
    QGraphicsView::update(region);
}

void GLGraphicsView::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    LOG4CXX_DEBUG(_logger, "repaint region " << e->region().boundingRect().x() << " " << e->region().boundingRect().y() << " " << e->region().boundingRect().width() << " " << e->region().boundingRect().height());

    /* Do the rest of the painting */
}
```

Output:

```
updateVideoRegion 19 19 1446 568
update(region) 19 19 1446 568
repaint region 0 0 1920 1201
```

Edit:

I've also tried using updateScene(QList) instead of update(QRegion), with viewportUpdateMode set to SmartViewportUpdate, but the paintEvent's region is still the full size of the screen. The CacheMode is set to CacheNone, and setting it to CacheBackground causes the OpenGL stuff to not be displayed.

Comment: `update` method is coming from `QWidget` base. Try to use `QGraphicsView::updateSceneRect` instead as its implementation should be more aware of `QGraphicsView`'s structure.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov - see my edit above - updateSceneRect doesn't appear to change anything according to the documentation, and updateScene doesn't make a difference to the paintEvent's region

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, it appears that this is because I am using OpenGL - the 'fullUpdate' flag in updateScene is always set in this case - qgraphicsView has "accelerateScrolling = !isGlWidget" [in setupViewport, line 2759] and "fullUpdate = !d->accelerateScrolling" [in updateScene, line 2675]

Comment: I have the same problem and I'm not using OpenGL. setViewportUpdateMode() is simply ignored.